# Как обновить data Vue.js, после нажатия на checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Не применяется фильтр к people, после нажатия на checkbox

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      checked: false,
      search: '',
      people: [
         { name: 'John',  age: 10 },
          { name: 'Mary',  age: 19 },
          { name: 'Mike',  age: 21 },
          { name: 'Adam',  age: 35 },
          { name: 'Julie', age: 29 }
        ],
   },
   computed: {
    filterPeople() {
      return this.people.filter( f => f.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changePeople() {
      if(this.checked) {
        return this.users.filter(f => f.age > 20)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" v-on:change="changePeople()">
    <label>Показывать больше 20</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" v-model="search">
    <label>Search on people</label>
  </div>
  <div id="app">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="person of filterPeople">
          <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checked: false,
    search: '',
    peoples: [{
        name: 'John',
        age: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Mary',
        age: 19
      },
      {
        name: 'Mike',
        age: 21
      },
      {
        name: 'Adam',
        age: 35
      },
      {
        name: 'Julie',
        age: 29
      }
    ],
    filtered_peoples: [],
  },
  watch: {
    checked(value) {
      this.filtered_peoples = this.getFilteredPeople();
    },
    search(value) {
      this.filtered_peoples = this.getFilteredPeople();
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.filtered_peoples = this.getFilteredPeople(false);
  },
  methods: {
    getFilteredPeople() {
      let peoples = [];

      if (this.checked) {
        peoples = this.peoples.filter(f => f.age > 20)
      } else {
        peoples = this.peoples
      }

      return peoples.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked">
    <label>Показывать больше 20</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" v-model="search">
    <label>Search on people</label>
  </div>
  <div id="app">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="person of filtered_peoples">
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```